# OrientDB serverside NullPointerException while serializing record using binary protocol

Tags: serialization, binary, protocols, orientdb, record

I've just started to implement binary protocol API to orientDB with C++. Current Version of used orientDB is "orientdb-community-2.2.29" with win 10 x64 and java 1.8. Since I've tried to query "select * from XXXX" on example DB serverside exceptions are thrown and no record is serialized to client. Here are the logs after successful connection and query:

```
2017-12-03 14:14:12:561 INFO  {db=Site} /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2520 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): null [OChannelBinaryServer]$ANSI{green {db=Site}} Error on unmarshalling record #73:0 (java.lang.NullPointerException)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.getRecordBytes(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:2894)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.writeRecord(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:2907)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.writeIdentifiable(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:2697)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.serializeValue(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1639)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1584)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:660)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:394)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:217)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:81)

2017-12-03 14:14:12:561 WARNI {db=Site} Cannot serialize record: XXXX#73:0{Name:[2],IDs:[1]} v3 [ONetworkProtocolBinary]
```

Before writing the "null" bytes the recordID, position and record version is serialized and received on client side correctly, also querying from Studio or console works like a charm. I've tried to change the class - property to STRING or EMBEDDEDMAP with the same problem.

Thanks in advance for help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found the mistake at my own: wrong SerializationImpl was configured. The correct configuration must be ORecordSerializerBinary and not ONetworkProtocolBinary.